# Unit testing a discrete Fourier transformation

Tags: java, unit-testing, fft

Several months ago I had to implement a two-dimensional Fourier transformation in Java. While the results seemed sane for a few manual checks I wondered how a good test-driven approach would look like.

Basically what I did was that I looked at reasonable values of the DC components and compared the AC components if they roughly match the Mathematica output.

My question is: Which unit tests would you implement for a discrete Fourier transformation? How would you validate results returned by your calculation?

Comment: This is a question for the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for other unit-tests, you should consider small fixed input test-vectors for which results can easily be computed manually and compared against. For the more involved input test-vectors, a direct DFT implementation should be easy enough to implement and used to cross-validate results (possibly on top of your own manual computations).

As far as specific test vectors for one-dimensional FFT, you can start with the following from [dsprelated](http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/71595/1.php), which they selected to exercise common flaws:

> - Single FFT tests - N inputs and N outputs
>
>   - Input random data
>   - Inputs are all zeros
>   - Inputs are all ones (or some other nonzero value)
>   - Inputs alternate between +1 and -1.
>   - Input is e^(8*j*2*pi*i/N) for i = 0,1,2, ...,N-1. (j = sqrt(-1))
>   - Input is cos(8*2*pi*i/N) for i = 0,1,2, ...,N-1.
>   - Input is e^((43/7)*j*2*pi*i/N) for i = 0,1,2, ...,N-1. (j sqrt(-1))
>   - Input is cos((43/7)*2*pi*i/N) for i = 0,1,2, ...,N-1.
> - Multi FFT tests - run continuous sets of random data
>
>   - Data sets start at times 0, N, 2N, 3N, 4N, ....
>   - Data sets start at times 0, N+1, 2N+2, 3N+3, 4N+4, ....

For two-dimensional FFT, you can then build on the above. The first three cases are still directly applicable (random data, all zeros, all ones). Others require a bit more work but are still manageable for small input sizes. 
Finally google searches should yield some reference images (before and after transform) for a few common cases such as black & white squares, rectangle, circles which are  can be used as reference (see for example http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/FFT_tests/).

Answer (score 2):

99.9% of the numerical and coding issues you will likely find will be found by testing with a **random complex vectors** and comparing with a **direct DFT** to a tolerance on the order of floating point precision.

Zero, constant, or sinusoidal vectors may help *understand* a failure by allowing your eye to catch issues like initialization, clipping, folding, scaling.  But they will not typically *find* anything that the random case does not.

My [kissfft](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) library does a few extra tests related to fixed point issues -- not an issue  if you are working in floating point.